# How to add Widgets to UpdateView in Django

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms, django-widget

I need to add this widget to the django UpdateView,

```
class tlistUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    fields = ('title', 'thumbnail', 'content', 'tags')
    model = htmlpage
    template_name = 'blog/create_form.html'
```

Tried adding

```
widgets = {
    'content': SummernoteWidget(),
}
```

and

```
content = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())
```

But it did't work.

Comment: Just use a form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `UpdateView` is not constructed to handle advanced form construction. The idea is that you use `fields` if you aim to construct a *simple* (standard) `Form`.

You can simply construct a `ModelForm` and use that form in your `CreateView`/`UpdateView`:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms

class HtmlPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HtmlPage
        fields = ('title', 'thumbnail', 'content', 'tags')
        widgets = {
            'content': SummernoteWidget
        }
```

In your `views.py` you can then use the form by setting the [**`form_class`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class):

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import HtmlPageForm

class TlistUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = htmlpage
    form_class = HtmlPageForm
    template_name = 'blog/create_form.html'
```

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `HtmlPage` instead of <s>`htmlpage`</s>.